# No error (but system reboots) when creating too many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to test whether my compiler (mingw 6.3) will generated std::system_error when creating large number of threads using std::thread, or deferred task execution when creating tasks using std::async.

... but for the first case it drained system resources to the point when system (windows 10) rebooted (I tested this two times). Also std::async in my opinion misbehaves as it does not genereate defered tasks - system is heavily slowed down, but does not reboots.

is this behaviour allowed by standard? I know I should check for deferred tasks, but in my opinion its difficult to test this code path when it cannot be reproduced even after generating 125000 threads. I am not saying my application is going to generate such number of threads, but some other process might abuse system resources in the background.

Code samples below.

sample code for generating large amount of threads (under mingw 6.3 and windows 10 ends with system reboot!)

```
 std::vector<std::thread> th_vec;
  std::atomic<bool> wait(true);
  for(std::size_t i= 0; ; ++i) {
    th_vec.emplace_back([&](){ while(wait){ std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); }});
    if ((th_vec.size()%100) == 0) {
      std::cout << "#" << (th_vec.size() / 100) << " th_vec.size() = " << th_vec.size() << "\n";
    }
  }
```

and task based aproach:

```
  std::vector<std::future<void>> fut_vec;
  std::vector<std::future<void>> fut_vec_defered;
  std::atomic<bool> wait(true);
  for(std::size_t i= 0; ; ++i) {
    auto fut = std::async([&](){ while(wait){ std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); }});

    if (fut.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::deferred) {
      // in my tests task is never deferred, even if 126K threads are generated
      fut_vec_defered.emplace_back(std::move(fut));
    } else
      fut_vec.emplace_back(std::move(fut));

    if ((i % 100) == 0) {
      std::cout << "#" << (i / 100) << " fut_vec.size() = " << fut_vec.size() << ", fut_vec_defered.size() = " << fut_vec_defered.size() << "\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: The standard covers a very broad set of hardware. When you run out of resources on a given platform, expect whatever behaviour the platform chooses to defend itself with.

Comment: By the way, unless you have 125000 available processor cores, 125000 threads is a performance-killing waste of time. Look into implementing a thread pool.